# Firestore database creation lock on GCP project restore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

We have restored a GCP project that had several resources associated to it. Among those there was a Firestore database. After restoring the project and verified everything, I noticed that the database was not shown in the console, it asks me to create a new one, which is strange since in theory any resource should be kept if restored within 30 days:

[image]

I tried to recreate the database and I receive an error that a database already exists for this project:

[image]

It seems like a big GCP issue. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Can you provide any screenshot or error message?

Comment: @RobertG Just added some screenshots. As a workaround I created a new project to populate the data in a new DB. In addition I cut a ticket for being unable to recover my previous project.

Comment: From user support they told me that my question was not related to be unable to access to a project and I should cut a tech ticket instead (that I need to pay for that). Worst user support ever.